# How to compare an element from an array to something else in an if statement?

Tags: javascript

It's probably super simple, but I don't know how to target an element from an array in an if statement. I've looked around, and I haven't found any answers, which is why I am asking you.
Here is an example:

```
var currentUser = [55];
```

How to compare the `55` to a boolean in an if statement?

Comment: Can you post an example of your code? What are you trying to do?

Comment: `if(currentUser[0] === 55){...}`

Comment: _"I've looked around, and I haven't found any answers"_ So that took you what, 3 or 4 seconds?

Comment: Arrays have indexes, so aryName[ index ] will give you the value of the element at that index. So `currentUser[0]` will return 55, which you can then compare. `currentUser[ currentUser.length - 1 ]` will give you the last element (also 55 since there's only one number in the array )

Comment: I'm working on a chat program, where I want to send the socket id of a user logging in, to the client. In the client I then want to compare that id to the id's of other users. Thanks @Ferus7. That really helped me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(currentUser.includes(55)) 
{

} // returns true
```

Maybe you mean this, otherwise i dont understand the question

Answer (score 0):

Javascript:

> The includes() method determines whether an array includes a certain
>   element, returning true or false as appropriate.

*Ex.:*

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
a.includes(2); // true 
a.includes(4); // false
```

*So:*

```
var array = ['foo', 'bar'];
var foo = 'foo';

if (array.includes('foo')) {
    //do something
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes?v=example

jQuery:

> Search for a specified value within an array and return its index (or
>   -1 if not found)

*Ex.:*

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
$.inArray(1, arr) !== -1; //true
$.inArray(4, arr) !== -1; //false
```

*So:*

```
var array = ['foo', 'bar'];
var bar = 'bar';

if ($.inArray('bar', array) !== -1) { //returns -1 to false
    //do something
}
```

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/